# AssertionError occurs to file not found when executing train.py

Tags: python, anaconda, labelimg

I am trying to execute python train.py within Anaconda prompt but I am receiving numerous line text and an AssertionError: File not found: div2.yaml.
As you can see my **div2.yaml** file is based on the coco128 thats linked to my datasets photos and validation.

**python train.py --img 640 --batch 16 --epochs 3 --data div2.yaml --weights yolov5s.pt**

I tried to Upload more screen prints to show the file directories, but it wont allow me.
The div2.yaml file is located in **C:\Users\Marti\Desktop\yolov5\Data**.
I have tried entering the full directory into the code but I have the same outcome.
I am not sure what is wrong, if someone can help

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the relevant parts of the code and the fulll traceback error as text.

Comment: Your command assumes `div2.yaml` is in the current directory.  If it isn't, then use the full pathname.

Comment: I did send screen prints but it seems to have not attached to my message?

Comment: my first thought was to use the full path --Data C:\Users\Marti\Desktop\yolov5\Data\div2.yaml but I get the same result

Comment: File "C:\Users\Marti\Desktop\yolov5\train.py", line 540, in main
    check_file(opt.data), check_yaml(opt.cfg), check_yaml(opt.hyp), str(opt.weights), str(opt.project)  # checks
  File "C:\Users\Marti\Desktop\yolov5\utils\general.py", line 435, in check_file
    assert len(files), f'File not found: {file}'  # assert file was found
AssertionError: File not found: C:\Users\Marti\Desktop\yolov5\Data\div2.yaml

Comment: (base) C:\Users\Marti\Desktop\yolov5>python train.py --img 640 --batch 16 --epochs 3 --data C:\Users\Marti\Desktop\yolov5\Data\div2.yaml --weights yolov5s.pt

Comment: `File not found: C:\Users\Marti\Desktop\yolov5\Data\div2.yaml` Sounds like .. the file isn't there.

Comment: But it's there...... Can I not send screen prints on here? Thanks